# Decompress bz2 files in 30,000 subfolders with python os walk?

Tags: python, compression, os.walk, bz2

I've got 30,000 folders and each folder contains 5 bz2 files of json data.

I'm trying to use os.walk() to loop through the file path and decompress each compressed file and save in the original directory.

```
import os
import bz2

path = "/Users/mac/PycharmProjects/OSwalk/Data"
for(dirpath,dirnames,files) in os.walk(path):

for filename in files:
    filepath = os.path.join(dirpath , filename)
     newfilepath = os.path.join(dirpath , filename + '.decompressed')

        with open(newfilepath , 'wb') as new_file , 
          bz2.BZ2File(filepath , 'rb') as file:

              for data in iter(lambda: file.read(100 * 1024) , b''):
                  new_file.write(data)
```

I'm getting the following error running the code.

```
File 
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/_compr 
ession.py", line 103, in read
data = self._decompressor.decompress(rawblock, size)
OSError: Invalid data stream
```

I've read that there can be an issue running the code on mac with decompressor method or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be trying to decompress your already decompressed results. You should filter them out.

```
import os
import bz2

path = "/Users/mac/PycharmProjects/OSwalk/Data"
for (dirpath, dirnames, files) in os.walk(path):
    for filename in files:
        # filter out decompressed files
        if filename.endswith('.decompressed'):
            continue

        filepath = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
        newfilepath = os.path.join(dirpath, filename + '.decompressed')

        with open(newfilepath, 'wb') as new_file,
            bz2.BZ2File(filepath, 'rb') as file:

            for data in iter(lambda: file.read(100 * 1024), b''):
                new_file.write(data)
```

Comment: I added in your if statement but the code still doesn't run. I'm wondering is it with the bz2 import module?

Comment: That depends. How do you compress these files?

Comment: I downloaded the files from web which came in .tar format. I converted the tar to a normal folder directory. The compression was done from the server I presume

Comment: I don't think bunzip2 works on mac. Seems like a linux package. I tried pip installing and got a does not satisfy message.
 Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement bunzip2 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for bunzip2